# Ansible: Command module not interpolating shell variable

Tags: shell, ansible, command

The following command fails most likely because it fails to interpolate the shell variable `packdir`

```
  - name: archive_artifacts.yml --> Clear git history from packs directories
    command: 'for packdir in {{ packs_dir }}/*; do rm -rf {{ packs_dir }}/"${packdir}"/.git; done'
    args:
      chdir: "{{ temp_build_directory }}"
```

`packs_dir` is a variable in the `defaults/main.yml` of the specific role:

`packs_dir: "packs"`

Is there a way of having the command module substituting both `ansible` **and** `shell` variables?

Comment: You probably need to use the `shell` module instead of the `command` module for starters.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way of having the command module substituting both ansible and shell variables?

Yes. Make sure the shell variable is present in the environment of the host, user and shell you run the command in.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    env_variable: SHELL
  tasks:
    - command: "echo ${{ env_variable }}"
      register: result
    - debug: msg="{{ result.stdout }}"
```